# "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

Tags: api, visual-studio-2017

`"An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension. C:\Users\mine\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5f2147be\ActivityLog.xml`"

This dialog box is shown when I am trying to build an API in Visual studio 2017. I have disabled all the extensions but still this dialog box is appearing. How I can solve this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please learning debugging in order to identify the problems and use try catch of get details of the exception. Then you are able to identify the problems yourself.

Please read this article  to learn more about debugging
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/debugging-with-visual-studio/

In order to catch exceptions use the following code block.

```
    try
{
   //your code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```